# How to run a regression in Julia on ALL variables in the dataset?

Tags: julia, regression

I want to run a regression on 160 variables and hence don't want to type in all the variable names. In R I would just type "y ~ ." but I don't know how to do that in Julia. Thanks!

I tried to use an R like approach but I failed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is your input data. Assuming you have it in a `df` data frame then the formula would be:

```
term(:y) ~ sum(term.(names(df, Not(:y))))
```

In other words there is no `.` operator, but you can programmatically construct the formula.

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I was searching for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: by using `term` instead of `Term` things are even simpler. I have updated the answer.